# Script timed out before returning headers

Tags: php, mysql, centos

У меня на сервере установлена CentOS и панель CWP. Там крутится 1 сайт. В админке сайта есть импорт прайса. В параметрах php выставлено такие параметры:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
```

Но когда пытаюсь сделать импорт, получаю ошибку ***Internal Server Error***
В логах пишет

```
Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: https://site.ua/admin/prices/import
```

Какие настройки надо еще изменить

Comment: лучше бы выставили этот параметр для конкретного скприта, который импортирует эти данные. Хотя возможно в нем и выставляется меньшее значение

Comment: выставил, вот например перед импортом задаются такие параметры ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); set_time_limit(0);

Comment: апач у вас там? у него тоже есть настройки времени ожидания. Сообщение об ошибке-то такое, не похожее на пхп-шное

Comment: проверил настройки апача - не нашел там такой настройки

Comment: Если nginx+php-fpm, то настройки таймаута могут быть и там и там. Если используется f(ast)cgi, то и в его настройках может быть таймаут

Comment: вы это в каком именно  логе читаете то?

Comment: /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

Comment: вроде сделал, задал параметр Timeout в настройках apache. Заработало